# PHP error with apostrophes (GET - POST - SESSION variables)

Tags: php, global-variables

As working on my localhost I use variables like $_GET['page'], $_SESSION[userid] etc.
But when I use this codes on my web server, it stops executing PHP file in first usage of a variable with aphostrophes (e.g. in index.php file it's $_GET['page']).

I removed all the aphostrophes, (as $_SESSION['userid'] -> $_SESSION[userid]). It worked, but some sessions problems occured.

What is the solution?

Comment: You mind sharing the error msg?

Comment: You want to know what the solution to "some problems" is? I guess, "some fix"

Comment: Removing the apostrophes is **extremely bad**. Add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to the beginning of your php files and you'll see why. Provide us some code and we can help you finding out the actual problem of your code!

Comment: Could you post the error message which you're receiving?

Comment: I added the line "error_reporting(E_ALL);" but I receive no error messages.

Comment: Are you sure you're starting your session on every page? `session_start()` must be at the top of every php page when you use the `$_SESSION` array

Comment: To get higher quality answers, write a [higher quality question](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints) by including [sample code](http://sscce.org/) that is complete yet concise, including e.g. HTML source, SQL statements or table defintions, and preferrably some sample data.
See also [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

> Just a guess, in absence of code.

If you say it worked without quotes, then I would assume the variables were mentioned somewhere in [double quote context](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double). There the `'` will lead to a parsing error:

```
print " <a href=index.php?page=$_GET['page']>...</a> ";
```

And on top of that it would be a silent fatal error, as adding `error_reporting()` in that very inded.php script would be too late.

Doesn't explain the vague session problem, or why it (supposedly) worked on the test server.

Answer (score 0):

The apostrophes should be there, not putting the apostrophes would generate a notice. Appart if you have defined a constant called userid but I doubt.

I think you should check the webserver logs.

Comment: s/warning/notice. And if he had such a constant it would probably break even more since it would unlikely to be defined to the string `userid`

Comment: @ThiefMaster: thanks, yeah it would break or at least be strange